# pointers and cast

Tags: c, pointers

Let's take this example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x = 1;
    if(*(char *)&x == 1) printf("little-endian\n");
    else printf("big-endian\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen this (or similar one) instruction `*(char *)&x` multiple times and now i want to completely understand what does it mean!
I think it means:
*1) take the address of the int variables

2) then cast it to a char pointer

3) then compare the first element of the "new char pointer" with the number 1.*
Am i right?

Comment: Remark on the code snippet: the strings printed are not necessarily correct. Just because the first byte is the least-significant doesn't necessarily mean the system is little-endian (although I don't think there exist any counter-examples). Just because the first byte is not the least-significant doesn't necessarily mean the system is big-endian (and there do exist counter-examples, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian). None of this relates to the meaning of the cast, of course.

Comment: this is also a bad way to determine endianness; if you really, really, really need to care, the OS should provide headers which will tell you which endianness you're compiling for; IIRC, it's <sys/endian.h> on linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're about right, but a better listing would be:

1. Take the address of `x`
2. Convert address into a pointer to character
3. Dereference that pointer, i.e. read the first `char` at `&x`
4. Compare character value to integer `1`

Note that this is rather edgy code, the read value will depend on the machine's byte endianness.